# Cassandra SSTableSplit - How are is the split achieved?

Tags: cassandra

Since Cassandra ships the sstablesplit tool to split large sstable files after a major compaction or SizeTieredCompaction. The question is: How does Cassandra know how to split the file right? I mean compaction compacted it and cleaned the sstable to a big one.

How can SSTableSplit ensure that the newly created smaller SSTables have a good read performance or are still optimized in terms for row/partition keys?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm at home so not able to do it myself but have you tried sstablesplit with verbose output?

Comment: Hey Simon, thanks for the feedback. Seems that the --verbose was changed to --debug but thanks for pointing me into the right direction!

Comment: Great that I could be of some help.